# Need button to stay at the bottom of my dialog

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, miglayout

I originally posted this question on the miglayout forum and after 534 views and no answers, I decided to try it there ;-)

I tried to extend the "initial example" from the MigLayout whitepaper in order to add an "OK" button that would always stay on the bottom of the dialog.

Unfortunately, the only solution I found was to add a "fake panel" that would grow:

```
public class TestResize extends JDialog {
    protected JPanel contentPane;

    public TestResize() {
        super((Dialog) null, "Test resize", true);
        setupUI();
        setContentPane(contentPane);
    }

    private void setupUI() {
        contentPane = new JPanel(new MigLayout());
        contentPane.add(new JLabel("Enter size:"), "");
        contentPane.add(new JTextField(""), "grow, pushx, wrap");
        contentPane.add(new JLabel("Enter weight:"), "");
        contentPane.add(new JTextField(""), "grow, pushx, wrap");
        // fake panel that is allowed to grow
        contentPane.add(new JPanel(), "span 2, grow, pushy, wrap");
        JButton okButton = new JButton("Ok");
        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel(new MigLayout("", "[center, grow]"));
        buttonPanel.add(okButton, "");
        contentPane.add(buttonPanel, "dock south");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestResize dialog = new TestResize();
        dialog.pack();
        dialog.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

I really don't like this approach at all... but is there a better way?

(Looks like I'm not allowed to upload pictures, but the UI I want to get is visible [in my original post](http://migcalendar.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=3776))

Thanks!

Comment: *"Unfortunately, the only solution I found was to add a "fake panel" that would grow:"*  What is unfortunate about that?  Extra panels are quite common in nested layouts.  No problem.

Comment: @AndrewThompson the whole idea of an advanced LayoutManager is to _not_ use nested panels nor hacks like glue or other dummy components ;-) Nesting and dummy components in MigLayout are indeed a very strong indicator of doing something wrong - just as laurent felt

Comment: @kleopatra  Ehh.. nothing wrong with a little glue and duck tape. ;) But more seriously, I see your point.  I get too used to core J2SE layouts to see the bigger picture at times.

Comment: @AndrewThompson: Russel's answer below perfectly solves my issue. I *knew* that MigLayout could do it without a fake panel, but the documentation is so exhaustive that it's sometimes difficult to find the correct keyword ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you construct the MigLayout with an explicit grid, you can have a ":push" in between two of the rows:

```
new MigLayout(
      "",                 // Layout Constraints
      "[][]",             // Column constraints
      "[][][]:push[]");   // Row constraints
```

(See the "Column/Row Constraints" section of the [cheatsheet](http://www.migcalendar.com/miglayout/mavensite/docs/cheatsheet.html))

**Edit:**

Actually, a better solution is to use "wrap push" at the end of the previous row. Then you don't need to explicitly set the number of rows in the grid:

```
contentPane.add(new JPanel(), "span 2, grow, pushy, wrap push");
```

Comment: Yes, exactly what I needed : by bye "fake panel" and thanks a lot Russel !

Comment: Alternatively you can use a "newline push" on the last component, the one that you want pushed to the bottom of the frame.